# Most elegant way to combine chrono::time_point from hours, minutes, seconds etc

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I have a "*human readable*" variables `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds`, `day`, `month`, `year` that contains values corresponding to their names (let's say I have `SYSTEMTIME` structure from `<windows.h>`).
The only way I found to create a `chrono::time_point` is:

```
SYSTEMTIME sysTime = ...; // Came from some source (file, network, etc. )
tm t;
t.tm_sec = sysTime.wSecond;
t.tm_min = sysTime.wMinute;
t.tm_hour = sysTime.wHour;
t.tm_mday = sysTime.wDay;
t.tm_mon = sysTime.wMonth - 1;
t.tm_year = sysTime.wYear - 1900;
t.tm_isdst = 0;
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point dateTime =
    std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t( mktime( & t ) );
```

First, I lost a milliseconds from `SYSTEMTIME`.
Second, (mmm...) I don't like this sort of conversion ))

Could you give a more elegant way to do this issue ?

Comment: If you have an **actual** `SYSTEMTIME`, see `SystemTimeToFileTime()`.

Comment: @MSalters `SystemTimeToFileTime()` gives me a number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601, but I need `chrono::time_point`

Comment: True. But that simplifies the math a bit. Get the FILETIME and `chrono::time_point` for 1-1-2000 (to prevent out of range issues - you can do this once), subtract that FILETIME from the current time, multiply by 10 to get microseconds, and add those microseconds to the 1-1-2000 time_point

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [this open source, header-only library](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), I can:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

struct SYSTEMTIME
{
    int wMilliseconds;
    int wSecond;
    int wMinute;
    int wHour;
    int wDay;
    int wMonth;
    int wYear;
};

int
main()
{
    SYSTEMTIME sysTime = {123, 38, 9, 10, 8, 7, 2015};
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point dateTime =
        date::sys_days(date::year(sysTime.wYear)
                      /date::month(sysTime.wMonth)
                      /date::day(sysTime.wDay))
        + std::chrono::hours(sysTime.wHour)
        + std::chrono::minutes(sysTime.wMinute)
        + std::chrono::seconds(sysTime.wSecond)
        + std::chrono::milliseconds(sysTime.wMilliseconds);
    std::cout << dateTime << '\n';
}
```

which outputs:

```
2015-07-08 10:09:38.123000
```

In "date.h", you may have to play around with these macros to get things to compile with VS.:

```
#  define CONSTDATA const
#  define CONSTCD11 
#  define CONSTCD14
```

With a std-conforming C++14 compiler, these macros should be set to:

```
#  define CONSTDATA constexpr
#  define CONSTCD11 constexpr 
#  define CONSTCD14 constexpr
```

Comment: How can a header-only library in a language without built-in networking support deal with leap seconds, whose existence isn't mathematically predictable?  If not, what do you do with leap seconds?

Comment: @Yakk: This library does not support leap seconds.  However I am nearly finished with another library, which layers on top of this one, which does handle leap seconds.  This other library is not header-only, and is a complete parser of the IANA timezone database:  http://www.iana.org/time-zones  The IANA database includes leap seconds in its data. This newer library is feature complete, but not yet documented.

Comment: Great(est) library. Thank you. Could you remove `using namespace` from answer and bring them back to all symbols to see what symbols are from your library and what ones from `chrono` ? Thank you ones more